# C, Windows API recursively navigate subdirectories

Tags: c, winapi, recursion

The program recursively navigates the given folder, creates registry for folders, but after the execution of the RegSetValueEx function nothing happend in the registry, what should I change ? I mean the program Works perfect but nothing change in registry about RegSetValuesEx function just RegCreateKeys worked well.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define DEFAULT_KEY_DIR "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"
#define DEFAULT_KEY_SUBDIR "Software\\CSSO"
#define DEFAULT_DIRECTORY "D:\\Example"
char xPath[2048] = "Software\\CSSO";

bool ListDirectoryContents(const char *sDir)  
{
WIN32_FIND_DATA fdFile;
HANDLE hFind = NULL;
LARGE_INTEGER filesize;
DWORD return_value;
char sPath[2048];
HKEY hKey;


sprintf(sPath, "%s\\*", sDir);

if ((hFind = FindFirstFile(sPath, &fdFile)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("Path not found: [%s]\n", sDir);
    return false;
}

do
{

    if (strcmp(fdFile.cFileName, ".") != 0
        && strcmp(fdFile.cFileName, "..") != 0)
    {

        sprintf(sPath, "%s\\%s", sDir, fdFile.cFileName);


        if (fdFile.dwFileAttributes &FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {

            printf("%s\n", sPath);
            memset(&xPath[0], 0, sizeof(xPath));
            strcpy(xPath, DEFAULT_KEY_SUBDIR);
            int j = strlen(DEFAULT_KEY_SUBDIR);
            for (int i = strlen(DEFAULT_DIRECTORY); i < strlen(sPath); i++)
            {
                xPath[j] = sPath[i];
                j++;
            }


                RegCreateKeyEx(
                HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
                xPath,
                0, 0, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
                KEY_ALL_ACCESS, 0, &hKey, 0
            );

            ListDirectoryContents(sPath); //Recursion, I love it!
        }
        else {
            filesize.LowPart = fdFile.nFileSizeLow;
            filesize.HighPart = fdFile.nFileSizeHigh;
            _tprintf(TEXT("%s  %ld bytes\n"),sPath, filesize.QuadPart);

            return_value = RegSetValueEx(
                hKey,
                fdFile.cFileName, 0,
                REG_DWORD,
                (BYTE*)filesize.QuadPart,
                strlen(sPath)
            );
        }
    }
} while (FindNextFile(hFind, &fdFile)); 

FindClose(hFind); 

return true;
}

int main()
{
ListDirectoryContents("D:\\Example");
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Every time a found entry is a directory, the function should call itself with the path of the found directory.

Comment: What @fvu says.  Note: full path, ie 'dir' concatted with \\ and ffd.cFileName

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks for answer guys, but i don't have already " dir " concatted with "\\" in path variable?

Comment: The "call itself" part **is** the recursion...

Comment: I know that, i did what u said and is not working...

Comment: OK, now test and debugger.  One folder, one file in folder, one subfolder, one file in subfolder.  Step through.

Comment: ' is not working' is not helpful:(

Comment: You ignore return values, you don't know whether or not the calls succeed therefore, and I can't see evidence of any attempt to debug. Try harder.

Comment: Please update the question title to reflect the issue. Apparently, you do not have any issue with what the question title claims. Also, provide a [mcve]. We don't need to see the directory traversal code, when you have issues writing to the registry.

Comment: Don't do this in C. Use a more appropriate language.

Comment: @Ben: The choice of language is part of the question. It's not subject to discussion.

Comment: @IInspectable  The code includes `using namespace std;`, `<iostream>`, so the asker is in fact using C++. Wrong title and tag!

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: I know. Still, the OP is not *using* any of those features. Who knows, this might be part of test code, that does use C++, and was kept due to sloppiness. Still, in general, that language tag is part of the question, and not subject to discussion.

Comment: My opinion is that you are too bad with new members in the community plus I have highlighted that I am a beginner in windows api, and my level knowledge in programming are pretty low.

Comment: @wannalearn I meant no insult. It's criticism against your code, not against you personally!

Comment: To each their own. My opinion is that too few new members are taking the [tour], and visit the [help]. This place is for *"professional and enthusiast"* programmers. It is not the place to have your hand held through your first baby steps, learning to program.

Comment: @IInspectable, it's not an answer, which is why it is a comment not an answer. Nor is it discussion about the question, it's advice to the poster to help solve whatever the underlying problem really is.

Comment: @wannalearn, If this is a learning project, I suggest you learn a different language. C# and Java are great first languages to learn. So is VB. Python is OK too. C is just not the right language for most programming problems, it's a language you use to make operating systems and other languages. Good luck!

Comment: @Ben: You appear to be misunderstanding the mission of Stack Overflow. It's not about the OP (as it would be in a forum). It's about the question. The OP being helped is just a side effect. Besides, C is a *very* good choice as a first programming language, as it teaches you a lot of things that are valuable in *any* programming language. Even if you never write any code in C. Its rules are also way more minimalistic than those in any of the programming languages you named.

Comment: Firstly, Comments are ephemera, they aren't part of the Q&A, they don't have to contribute to the core mission, and frequently don't - look around. Secondly, Stack Overflow itself is not the end, it is only the means. The end is helping people. That's why I am involved, not to build a sterile library. Thirdly, Why do you say it is not up for discussion then insist on discussing it? @IInspectable

Comment: @Ben: I'm not discussion the applicability of C for the task at hand, nor that it is a requirement. Secondly, Stack Overflow *is* that *"sterile library"* you don't want it to be, because that's why it's there. If you feel like turning it into a forum, you might find yourself running against objection. The End.

Answer (score 2):

Above code is going through a recursive loop, it is adding a lot of junk to the registry. This is not recommended.

```
return_value = RegSetValueEx(
            hKey,
            fdFile.cFileName, 0,
            REG_DWORD,
            (BYTE*)filesize.QuadPart,
            strlen(sPath))
```

`(BYTE*)filesize.QuadPart` is wrong. It is similar to writing:

```
BYTE* ptr = (BYTE*)123;
```

This creates a pointer to the memory address 123 which we are not allowed to mess with. You mean to write `(BYTE*)&filesize.QuadPart` instead.

Assuming that you want to write the filesize, use `REG_QWORD` instead of `REG_DWORD`. Use `sizeof(filesize.QuadPart)` instead of `strlen(path)`.

```
if (ERROR_SUCCESS != RegSetValueEx(hKey, fdFile.cFileName, 0, REG_QWORD, 
    (BYTE*)&filesize.QuadPart, sizeof(filesize.QuadPart))
{
    printf("RegSetValueEx error\n");    
}
```

However, you should use the registry for adding initialization data only. If you have a lot of data then save to file, or just save it in memory.

Comment: I didn't see your answer, I figure it out myself I will post the answer maybe will help someone.

Answer (score -2):

I figured out what I did wrong, thank you guys for answers I will post the final code maybe will help someone.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define DEFAULT_KEY_DIR "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"

#define DEFAULT_KEY_SUBDIR "Software\\CSSO"

#define DEFAULT_DIRECTORY "D:\\Example"
char xPath[2048] = "Software\\CSSO";


bool ListDirectoryContents(const char *sDir)

{
WIN32_FIND_DATA fdFile;
HANDLE hFind = NULL;
LARGE_INTEGER filesize;
DWORD return_value;
char sPath[2048];
HKEY hKey, hKey2;

//Specify a file mask. *.* = We want everything!
sprintf(sPath, "%s\\*", sDir);

if ((hFind = FindFirstFile(sPath, &fdFile)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("Path not found: [%s]\n", sDir);
    return false;
}

do
{
    //Find first file will always return "."
    //    and ".." as the first two directories.
    if (strcmp(fdFile.cFileName, ".") != 0
        && strcmp(fdFile.cFileName, "..") != 0)
    {
        //Build up our file path using the passed in
        //  [sDir] and the file/foldername we just found:

        sprintf(sPath, "%s\\%s", sDir, fdFile.cFileName);

        //Is the entity a File or Folder?
        if (fdFile.dwFileAttributes &FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {

            printf("%s\n", sPath);
            memset(&xPath[0], 0, sizeof(xPath));
            strcpy(xPath, DEFAULT_KEY_SUBDIR);
            int j = strlen(DEFAULT_KEY_SUBDIR);
            for (int i = strlen(DEFAULT_DIRECTORY); i < strlen(sPath); i++)
            {
                xPath[j] = sPath[i];
                j++;
            }


            RegCreateKeyEx(
                HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
                xPath,
                0, 0, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
                KEY_ALL_ACCESS, 0, &hKey, 0
            );

            ListDirectoryContents(sPath); //Recursion, I love it!
        }
        else {
            filesize.LowPart = fdFile.nFileSizeLow;
            filesize.HighPart = fdFile.nFileSizeHigh;
            _tprintf(TEXT("%s  %ld bytes\n"), sPath, filesize.QuadPart);

            RegOpenKeyEx(
                HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
                xPath,
                REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
                KEY_WRITE,
                &hKey);

            RegSetValueEx(
                hKey,
                fdFile.cFileName, NULL,
                REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&filesize.QuadPart,
                sizeof(DWORD));

        }
    }
} while (FindNextFile(hFind, &fdFile)); //Find the next file.

FindClose(hFind); //Always, Always, clean things up!

return true;

}


int main()

{
ListDirectoryContents("D:\\Example");
system("PAUSE");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: This is using `REG_DWORD` and `sizeof(DWORD)` to store 4 bytes. But `filesize.QuadPart` is 8 bytes. That should be fine if the files of interests are all under 4Gb. You can just save `fdFile.nFileSizeLow` in that case.

Comment: Advice must come with a rationale, so that you have a way to know, when good advice turns bad. Code-only answers are not very useful. An answer must at the very least explain what the core issue is, and how the proposed solution addresses it. Well, and it must be correct. This proposed answer is none of that.